# How to toggle a hamburger button in Laravel using Vue?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to get the hamburger toggle to open and close when clicked. I am using Laravel, Tailwindcss, Vue.

My issue is I am confused about where to actually put the JS/Vue code.

I have js.app file, bootstrap.js file, components->exampleComponent (Vue file), but then there's also the Sass folder and files including the Webpack.mix

Where would I put this logic and why?

```
const Vue = require("vue");
new Vue({
    el: "#nav",
    data: {
        isOpen: false
    },
    methods: {
        toggle() {
            this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
        }
    }
});
```

Heres my webpack.mx.js file

```
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");

mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.js")]
    });
```

Layout page

```
<div>
  <!---- Nav Bar --->
  <nav id="nav" class="bg-gray-800">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
        <div class="flex items-center">
          <div class="flex-shrink-0">
            <img class="h-10 w-10" src="/images/startup.svg" alt="icon" />
          </div>
          <div class="hidden md:block">
            <div class="ml-10 flex items-baseline">
              <a href="/home"
                class="px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Home</a>
              <a href="/about"
                class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">About</a>
              <a href="/portfolio"
                class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Portfolio</a>
              <a href="/posts"
                class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Blog</a>
              <a href="/contact"
                class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Contact</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden md:block">
          <div class="ml-4 flex items-center md:ml-6">
            <button
              class="p-1 border-2 border-transparent text-gray-400 rounded-full hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700"
              aria-label="Notifications">
              <button>
                <a href="#"
                  class="px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium text-white bg-green-500 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Sign
                  Up</a>
              </button>
            </button>

            <!-- Profile dropdown -->
            <div class="ml-3 relative">
              <div>
                <button
                  class="max-w-xs flex items-center text-sm rounded-full text-white focus:outline-none focus:shadow-solid"
                  id="userMenu" aria-label="userMenu" aria-haspopup="true">
                  <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="/images/0.jpeg" alt="" />
                </button>
              </div>

              <!--
                Profile dropdown panel, show/hide based on dropdown state.

                Entering: "transition ease-out duration-100"
                  From: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                  To: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-75"
                  From: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                  To: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
              -->
              <div class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mr-2 flex md:hidden">
          <!-- Mobile menu button -->
          <button @click="toggle"
            class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700 focus:text-white">

            <!-- Menu open: "hidden", Menu closed: "block" -->
            <svg class=" block h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
            </svg>
            <!-- Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden" -->
            <svg class="hidden h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--
      Mobile menu, toggle classes based on menu state.

      Open: "block", closed: "hidden"
    -->
    <div v-show="isOpen" class="hidden md:hidden">
      <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 sm:px-3">
        <a href="/homne"
          class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Home</a>
        <a href="/about"
          class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">About</a>
        <a href="/portfolio"
          class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="/blog"
          class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Blog</a>
        <a href="/contact"
          class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div class="pt-4 pb-3 border-t border-gray-700">
        <div class="flex items-center px-5">
          <div class="flex-shrink-0">
            <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
              alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="ml-3">
            <div class="text-base font-medium leading-none text-white">#</div>
            <div class="mt-1 text-sm font-medium leading-none text-gray-400">Email Address</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" mt-3 px-2">
          <a href="#"
            class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Your
            Profile</a>
          <a href="#"
            class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Settings</a>
          <a href="#"
            class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Sign
            out</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <header class="bg-white shadow">
</div>
</header>

<body class="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
  <main class="flex-grow">
    <!-- Replace with your content -->
    @yield('content')
    <!-- /End replace -->
    </div>
  </main>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you using vue-cli?

Comment: I install via composer require laravel/ui

Answer (score 0):

In your  webpack.mx.js file on 2nd line it states already

`"resources/js/app.js"` is the root path

Comment: Ok good to know. This is where I placed the above logic. However, the toggle is not functioning? Added the view source code in the original post.

Comment: content of `<nav id="nav">codes</nav>` should be in app.js file